# PostgresSQL: could not stat directory "base/<db_oid>": Unknown error

Tags: windows, postgresql

I am getting error in starting PostgreSQL server after a machine restart on windows server 2019.

This server has a multiple databases and in logs it is showing error for one of the database may be corrupted.

I tried restart server few times, but it it is getting shut down after some time. How can I make server up again with other databases running?

```
    2022-04-20 07:32:49.843 PDT [3720] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.3,       compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit     
    2022-04-20 07:32:49.844 PDT    [3720] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432     
    2022-04-20 07:32:49.844 PDT [3720] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432     
    2022-04-20 07:32:57.949 PDT [6600] LOG:  database system       was interrupted while in recovery at 2022-04-20 06:29:00 PDT           
    2022-04-20 07:32:57.949 PDT [6600] HINT:  This probably means that       some data is corrupted and you will have to use the last    backup for      recovery.     
    2022-04-20 07:34:29.599 PDT [852] FATAL:  the database       system is starting up     
2022-04-20 07:44:04.349 PDT [2480] FATAL:  the     database system is starting up     
2022-04-20 07:52:28.107 PDT [4800]       FATAL:  the database system is starting up     
2022-04-20 08:09:30.847       PDT [1872] FATAL:  the database system is starting up     
2022-04-20 08:21:41.884 PDT [6600] LOG:  could not stat file "./base/22504705":     Unknown error     
2022-04-20 08:21:47.121 PDT [6600] LOG:  database       system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress           
2022-04-20 08:22:01.957 PDT [6600] LOG:  redo starts at 22E/5419D678     2022-04-20 08:22:01.994 PDT [6600] FATAL:  could not    stat directory      "base/22504705": Unknown error     
 2022-04-20 08:22:01.994 PDT [6600]       CONTEXT:  WAL redo at 22E/5422EDD8 for Heap/LOCK: off 3: xid       26378859: flags 0x00    LOCK_ONLY KEYSHR_LOCK  
2022-04-20 08:22:02.000      PDT [3720] LOG:     startup process (PID 6600) exited with exit code 1          
2022-04-20 08:22:02.000 PDT [3720] LOG:  aborting startup due to       startup process failure     
2022-04-20 08:22:02.085 PDT [3720] LOG: database system is shut down
```

[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuYzo.png)

Comment: Any anti-virus program running and "protecting" the Postgres data directory?

Comment: No, there is no antivirus program. While there was backgroud worker running data compression asynchronously when as i  restarted the machine.

Comment: Finally, I gaveup  after 24 hours and run forceful resetwal and now server is restarted. Fortunately, I dont see any data loss on the mentioned database.  While Stil need to verify other databases.